# Error with data-role="table" jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table

I am using table for layout. However with data role="table" I am getting following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'not' of undefined ".

I am using 
jquery-1.9.1.min.js;

jquery-ui.min.js;

jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js versions.

If i remove data-role then table structure gets affected. How should I avoid this error with data-role table option?

```
empDetails += '<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2" border="0" >';
        empDetails += '<tbody><tr><td colspan="100%"><img id="emailimg" src="images/email.png" class="imgshape"><IMG style="width:25px;height:5px;vertical-align:middle" SRC="images/spacer.gif" />';
        empDetails += stremail+'</span></a></td></tr>';
        empDetails += '<tr><td colspan="100%"><img id="emailimg" src="images/tel.png" class="imgshape"><IMG style="width:25px;height:5px;vertical-align:middle" SRC="images/spacer.gif" />';
        empDetails += strphone+'</td></tr>';
        empDetails += '<tr><td colspan="100%"><img id="emailimg"   src="images/cell.png" class="imgshape"><IMG style="width:25px;height:5px;vertical-     align:middle" SRC="images/spacer.gif" />';
        empDetails += strcellphone+'</td></tr>';

        empDetails += '</tbody></table>';

        $('#userdetails').html(empDetails);
```

MAngesh

Comment: can you show your actual code?

Comment: i doubt that is throwing the error... post you relted codes to..

Comment: Make sure your jQuery Mobile and jQuery versions are compatible, and make sure you're not using any other versions of either in the same page.

Comment: Try adding a <thead></thead> to the code.

Comment: Any updates On this issue. I have not solved this issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following line:

```
empDetails += '<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2" border="0" >';    
empDetails += '<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use following format in jquery mobile when table has data-role="table"
>   property:

```
 <table data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-priority="2">Rank</th>
                  <th>Movie Title</th>
                  <th data-priority="3">Year</th>
                  <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
                  <th data-priority="5">Reviews</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>1</th>
                  <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
                  <td>1941</td>
                  <td>100%</td>
                  <td>74</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>2</th>
                  <td>Casablanca</td>
                  <td>1942</td>
                  <td>97%</td>
                  <td>64</td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
</table>
```